# RS232 sending ETX, but machine not responding

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am trying to setup a simple program to a Spellman power supply.

I have setup a serialport object and included a timer to try RS232 connection.

Serial port configuration:

- COM4
- 9600 baud rate
- 8 data bit
- One stop bit

No handshaking is needed for this device.

I am having an issue because I need to send a SPECIFIC string to the Spellman
which I was told this would work:

```
STX22,pETX
```

But this does not work, I get no response.

Here is the problem: I have seen other examples, where the `Tx` or transmit line sends, `22,p^L`.  The `^L` is a special looking character that is smaller and raised. What is this character and how do I send it in C#?

It seems that little character is what I need instead of the ETX part of the string because the hardware responds back.

The cabling works fine -- I shorted the 2 and 3 wire and I get back exactly what I sent in my program.

I have also tried sending it all data in hex instead of ASCII string, and it also does not work.

I also tried using \0002 and \0003 in many different forms for STX and ETX, does not work. I just need to figure out this `22,p^L` issue.

Also this `22,p^L` I have only seen in LabVIEW programs.

Comment: Have you set the proper parity? STX and ETX are `\u0002` and `\u0003` not `\0002` and `\0003`.

Comment: Please indicate the EXACT model of Spellman Power Supply you are using.  Please provide link(s) to any examples you are referring to (Labview or otherwise).

Comment: You indicated that you have tried sending HEX data rather than an ASCII string.  Please post the exact HEX bytes you are using.

Comment: Yes the parity is correct. Yes I used \u0002 and \u0003. No response with those. Spellman Power Supply Model: DXB 140PN300. I do not have links to the programs. An example of the LabVIEW program when showing Tx and Rx, Tx: 22,p^L Rx: 22,33,45,55,76, etc....these are not EXACT feedbacks, I am just showing what I saw. It is a Spellman Supplied GUI.

Comment: Here is some hex that corresponds to the ASCII string: You would send  the following ASCII string:
STX22,pETX
Which corresponds to following hexadecimal string:
0232322C7003
This is the hex, which I also tried. The user manual also has this syntax for communication: 
<STX><22><,><CSUM><EXT>.    Also I used EXT not ETX, that was just a typo from earlier, so I tried "STX22,pEXT" and also "22,p" and also "\u000222,p\u0003" just for the heck of it, does not work.

Comment: I can also note that LabVIEW may have separated these hex bytes into a byte array and converted each one separately. I have looked into that with no luck, but '03' as a byte may = '^L' mysteriously , which is what I have seen on the end of these command strings.

Comment: My parity is set to NONE, which is what the manual said to do.

Comment: As best I can tell from the information provided, the HEX values you are using should work.  NOTE: `<STX>` and `<ETX>` are not optional and correlate to the starting byte of `0x02` and the ending byte of `0x03`.  The lower case "p" has a value of `0x70` which is a properly calculated `<CSUM>` value for the bytes in this command.

Comment: One more question:  have you tried the following string exactly:  `<STX>22,p<ETX>`  
The difference here is that the symbols for '<' and '>' **have been left in as a part of the string**.  Make sense?

Comment: Why are you setting 9600 baud?  This equipment seems to support 115K baud and use it as a default.  Have you tried it with 115K baud rate?

Comment: @YoungPadwan -- If you want help then show your code, i.e. a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem.  Otherwise your question is off-topic.  Also add the details that have been requested into your original post, instead of leaving scattered comments.